# WPF Browser Application for new Project?

Tags: c#, wpf, web-applications, xbap

We are gathering requirements for a web application project and the results show that a wpf web application (xbap) would be a good solution for us. but i am not sure if we should build a project upon this technology. i read some posts in stackoverflow and many people indicate that wpf browser applications are dead. 
what do you think ? Will microsoft continue to support wpf browser application in the future ?

I know my question is opinion based, but thats exactly what i want: your opinion.

Comment: It is too bad we have an exact close reason to match opinion based questions, sorry. Try a traditional forum, like Quora or Reddit instead. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe